# error:an error occur in php(jqgrid)?shall i need what this going to be refer?

Tags: php, jqgrid

```
TypeError: b(e.target).closest is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

Q=b(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow");
```

this error occur during my process.

for what reason this error is occur.

Answer (score 0):

closest() is a jquery function.  Have you included jquery?

Also note this is not a php issue this is javascript or jquery.

Comment: yes i have include jquery,(jquery-1.2.6.min.js this is the version.)

Comment: Thats a pretty old version of jquery.  Which version of jqgrid are you using?  Have you tried a jquery version above 1.4?  Try 1.4.3, its packaged with jqgrid, last commited 2 years ago.  I'd think that would be a good start.

Comment: i am placed your telling version sir 'js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js' but still now i get the same error sir.

Comment: @AravinthaBashyam: You should post *in which order* you include the JavaScript files? First of all you should read documentation. See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file) an example of simple page with jqGrid. You don't yet answered **which version of jqGrid**  you use? Moreover it's helpful to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in case of JqvqScript errors.

Comment: hai sir,oleg i try  jquery.jqGrid.min.js by this way sir still now i will get this error sir @Oleg

Comment: hai sir i try all the possible factors sir,@shapeshifter so if any other possible way please say to me sir,

Comment: @AravinthaBashyam: I wrote in my last comment questions to you. You should post HTML which shouws the **order of JavaScript files** which you includes. You should answer on the question: **which version of jqGrid you use**? If you post some JavaScript errors you should always use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min(1).js"></script> this are the things you asking mr.@Oleg.

Comment: Sorry mate but we need some context.  So far you have given an error and a line of html that includes a javascript file.  I don't know how your calling jqgrid.